# How can FileInputStream.read change my byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, fileinputstream

In the program I am writing for homework I have a `FileInputStream` which I am reading bytes from into an array using the `read()` method of the stream. I am not using the return value at all in my program, as I'm not interested in it.

However, I'm wondering how is it actually modifying my array? I read through many stackoverflow posts lasts night that indicated that Java is pass by value, not by reference, and I even proved it myself with a simple program.

How does this method modify my byte array?

```
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(FileName);
    bytes = new byte[input.available()];
    input.read(bytes); // reads file in as bytes and stores into bytes
    System.out.println(bytes[0]);


}catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Call by value doesn't mean that an object can't be mutated. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3824919) explains that.

Comment: The variable bytes is actually a reference to the array object. When you pass array to a method you are copying the reference not the actual array the the reference refers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java passes the *reference* to the byte array to the `read` method *by value*. This means that the `read` method cannot make your local variable `bytes` point to a different byte array, but it can change the contents of the byte array that you passed into it.

(If Java were "pass by reference", then a method could make your local variable point to a different object - which is not possible in Java)